# Slicing Ragged Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bunch of sliced images (32 x 32 in shape) stored each with a corresponding string id (file name and such). The slices and their ids are grouped in a bunch of arrays part of a final large array. This array is ragged and non-standard, but I'd like to be able to efficiently access the slices inside.

Let's say that I have 500 slices. The shape should be (500, 2) on the surface because the first grouping of slices and ids is not a standard array with given shape.

What I would like to be able to do is extract the sliced images themselves from the final array. Normally, I could collect everything by slicing the big array like `big_array[:][:][0]` but the ragged nesting has made the array appear 1D with shape (500, ).

The only way around this is to use a clunky for loop, but I'm pretty sure everything I've been doing up until this point has been a terrible way of storing the data.

I need to keep the ids associated with each slice because I'm training a model with this, and if something goes wrong, I'd like to be able to reference the origins of the slice which has undergone some processing.

The only other way around this is to store the ids and slices separately, but that is also a lot of hassle since I have to save them in separate files.

What's the correct way to store this thing?

Comment: Not `big_array[:][:][0]` but `big_array[:,:,0]`.  A `[:]` slices does nothing.  In any case a 1d object dtype array can only be indexed with 1 dimension.  Ragged arrays are not 'efficient'; you might as well consider them to be lists.

Comment: There isn't one correct way. Two arrays, (n,2) object dtype,structure array are all possibilities.  1d with n 2 element arrays feels like the worst.